# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Code in "/pages/blog/index.js" :

```
import BlogComponents from "../../components/Blog/blogComponents";
import { listBlogs } from "../../server/mongodb";

const index = async (props) => {
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>BLOG TITLE</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta httpEquiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
      </Head>
      <h1>BLOG HEADER</h1>
      <BlogComponents />
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  var blogs = await listBlogs();
  try {
    return {
      props: { blogs }
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
export default index;
```

Code in "../../server/mongodb.js":

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
// URI for mongodb
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI
const options = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }

// Mongoose Client Promise
mongoose.connect(uri, options)
import {Blog} from "./mongooseModels/blogModel";

export async function listBlogs() {
    let blogs = await Blog.find().lean();
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(blogs));
    
  return JSON.stringify(blogs);

}
```

End goal is to get all blog posts with their properties and integrate them into a react/nextjs component.
A console.log to the "props" argument in index.js returns:

```
{
  blogs: `[{"_id":"HEXID","title":"Blog Title","author":"ME","date":{"day":"27","month":"January","year":"2021"},"image":"/images/image.jpg","alt":"image alt","summary":"blog summary","content":["blog content "]},{"_id":"61f8c1953907a8bef3dcb4ff","title":"Blog Title 2","author":"ME","date":{"day":"27","month":"January","year":"2021"},"image":"/images/image.jpg","alt":"image alt","summary":"blog summary","content":["blog content"]}]`
}
```

Current error is:
error - Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
However the page is able to recieve the data returned from getServerSideProps()

** EDIT / Solution **
Figured it out... The error was not coming from the return statement in getServerSideProps(). It was instead coming from the  component. In preparation for connecting to a DB, I added, "async" to the  component which in turn started throwing the error.
Disappointed that NextJS wouldn't tell you where the "promise" is coming from in the returned error.

Comment: Try to set a variable first for the promise. ```const blogs = await Promise.all(blogArr)``` and then set ```blogsDB : blogs```.

Comment: Right now your returning the Promise object.

Comment: Where is `getServerSideProps` called/used? Can you update to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You've also a lot of waiting for things that aren't asynchronous in that function. Can you also share what `listBlogs` is?

Comment: Please share the React component code for that page.

Comment: @Arcanus I did what you suggested and am now getting:
error - Error: Error serializing `._id` returned from `getServerSideProps` in "/blog".
Reason: `object` ("[object Object]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.
Running this on a NextJS instance

Comment: Try to do JSON.parse(blogs)

Comment: @DrewReese I am running this on my page index.js
Located in ../../mongodb.js:
```
async function listBlogs() {
  const client = await clientPromise
  const db = client.db(dbName)
  const collection = db.collection(dbcollection)
  const docs = await collection.find({}).toArray()

  return docs
}
```

Comment: @Arcanus I cannot JSON.parse() since the return of "blogs" is an array of objects. I get a syntax error.

Comment: you need to parse the objects not the array

Comment: Can you also share the page component you are rendering?

Comment: @drewReese I added the whole index.js
I'm not doing anything really with the input from the DB yet. Waiting on having something working come through, before I do more work on the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your index blog component should not be declared `async`. React function components are pure, synchronous functions.

```
const index = async (props) => { // <-- implicitly returns Promise object
  console.log(props)
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>BLOG TITLE</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta httpEquiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
      </Head>
      <h1>BLOG HEADER</h1>
      <BlogComponents />
    </div>
  );
};

export default index; // <-- implicitly returned Promise object
```

The component should a synchronous function.

```
const index = (props) => { 
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props);
  }, [props]);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>BLOG TITLE</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta httpEquiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
      </Head>
      <h1>BLOG HEADER</h1>
      <BlogComponents />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Code was changed to match suggestion. Still getting:
error - Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @slay3r9903 Hmm, I see. Think you could try creating a *running* codesandbox demo of your code (*there's a Nextjs template*) that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live? Mock any data utilities like calls to the DB.

Comment: I edited my question to include the answer. I guess the "promise" wasn't coming from the return statement in getServerSideProps(). It was instead throwing the error due to me adding "async" to the BlogComponents component. After removing the async, the page loads as it should.
Thanks for the help, pointing out that React components should be synchronous, helped a lot.
I've literally been working on this on and off for a week...

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I was getting the same error, couldn't figure it out initially, as the error message is rather ambiguous.

Then I noticed I've declared my react component with the async keyword, which returns a Promise and this is what React was complaining about. React functional components cannot return promise objects. Otherwise, using async functions within useEffect() works fine.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const url = 'https://api.github.com/userssss'; // /users is correct, /usersssss returns error response.

const FetchTest = () => {
// React component cannot be promise object, must be pure object
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

const fetchDataExample = async () => {
// but we can have async functions within useEffect()
try {
  let response = await fetch(url);

  if (!response.ok) {
    setIsError(true); // this is a gotcha, because fetch() doesn't treat 4xx and 5xx as errors,
    // thusly, the catch() block will not run if remote resource is not found. So we need to handle the error response like this as well.
    // If Axios is used, this issue is not present and catch() will run on err.
    return;
  }
  // Order of our code in Javascript does matter, thats why we add our error-checking condition first and only after it
  // we write the rest of our code that handles success response
    let users = await response.json();
    setUsers(users);

    console.log(users);

    return users; // do we need to return anything?
} catch (error) {
    setIsError(true);
    console.log(error.message);
}
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetchDataExample();
}, []);
```

Comment: I was moving from App routing back to Page routing and this was the issue