# Can't get the fetched data to rendering on the page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

#### code in pages/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ListProducts from '@/components/products/ListProducts';




const getProducts = async () => {
  const data = await axios.get(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/products`);
  return data

};

const Homepage = () => {
  const productsData = getProducts();
  return <ListProducts data={productsData} />;
};

export default Homepage;
```

```
"use client";

import React from "react";
import Filters from "./Filters";
import ProductItem from "./ProductItem";

const ListProducts = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <section className="bg-green-50 py-12 ">
      <article className="max-w-screen-3xl mx-auto px-4 flex ">
        <Filters />
        <article className="grid grid-cols-2">
          {data?.products?.map((product) => (
            <ProductItem key={product?._id} product={product} />
          ))}
        </article>
      </article>
    </section>
  );
};

export default ListProducts;
```

```
const ProductItem = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <article className="border border-gray-200 overflow-hidden    bg-slate-300 shadow-md rounded mb-5 grid w-full">
      <img
        src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/89/2a/a5/892aa521d0a9c24646c7dd153b8f442a.jpg"
        alt=""
      />
      <p className="text-white text-lg"> {product?.name}</p>
    </article>
  );
};
export default ProductItem;
```

In console the data displaying properly..I cant display the data on the page...

```
Promise {<fulfilled>: {…}}

[[Prototype]]: Promise

[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"

[[PromiseResult]]: Object

config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}

data:

products: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

[[Prototype]]: Object

headers: AxiosHeaders {content-length: '567', content-type: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', date: 'Sun, 29 Oct 2023 07:35:26 GMT', etag: '"76gcorsd0nfr"', vary: 'Accept-Encoding'}

request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}

status: 200

statusText: "OK"

[[Prototype]]: Object
```

in the homepage function if i add async/await got this error.[Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70901826/objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-found-object-promise-if-you-meant-t)

Answer (score 0):

Products appears **undefined** because you are trying to render the page before the response to the request arrives.

The state method solves this problem. If no data is received, the page will not be rendered.

can you try this piece of code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ListProducts from '@/components/products/ListProducts';

const Homepage = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState()

  const getProducts = async () => {
    const data = await axios.get(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/products`);
    setProducts(data)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts()
  },[])

  if(products) return <ListProducts data={products} />;
  else return 'loading...'
};

export default Homepage;
```

Comment: Thank you for responding..I tried this piece of code but no luck.. I have the same result like before..the data were perfectly displaying in the console but in the page not..

Comment: Additionally the application breaks when trying to change something...